# Change the audio track label in videojs using HLS

Tags: typescript, http-live-streaming, video.js

I am using `video.js` with `DASH` and `HLS` depending on the platform that opens the website. My problem is that the manifest files are not containing the audio track label properly so I wanted to change it using the following code:

```
    const audioTrackList = this.player.audioTracks();
    
    for (let i = 0; i < audioTrackList.length; i++) {
      const element = audioTrackList[i];
      
      switch (this.get3LetterLangCode(element.language)) {
        case 'hun':
          element.label = this._translate.instant('Hungarian');
          break;
        case 'slk':
          element.label = this._translate.instant('Slovakian');
          break;
        case 'ron':
          element.label = this._translate.instant('Romanian');
          break;
        case 'bul':
          element.label = this._translate.instant('Bulgarian');
          break;
        case 'cze':
          element.label = this._translate.instant('Czech');
          break;
        case 'eng':
          element.label = this._translate.instant('English');
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
```

When I am using the `DASH` source this works correctly, but when I am using the `HLS` source then I get the following error message: `Attempted to assign to readonly property`

How can I change the audio track label when using HLS?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works fine for both Dash and HLS:

```
this.player.on('loadeddata', () => {
    let languageNames = new Intl.DisplayNames([],{type: 'language'});

    const audioTrackList = this.player.audioTracks();
    
    for (let i = 0; i < audioTrackList.length; i++) {
      const element = audioTrackList[i];
      element.label = languageNames.of(element.language)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem `Attempted to assign to readonly property`.

My solution is a bit ugly but it works.

```
const audioTrackList = this.player.audioTracks();
for (let i = 0; i < audioTrackList.length; i++) {
    let track = audioTrackList[0];
    this.player.audioTracks().removeTrack(track);
    const newTrack = new videojs.default.AudioTrack({...track, label: track.language, kind: 'main'});
    this.player.audioTracks().addTrack(newTrack as any);
}
```